# SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' when using bimbam.py

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I use the bimbam command:

```
bimbam.py "C:\In\ExampleFile.exe" "C:\Out"
```

I get an error saying `SyntaxError: missing parentheses in call to 'print'` I'm not using the print command so what is wrong? Im using Python 3.6...

Comment: Are you using a module in `bimbam.py` that is not Python 3 ready? You should show your code.

Comment: Please show your code or we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

Python no longer accepts commands with strings in this format:

```
print"Hello world!"
```

Python needs this format:

```
print("Hello world!")
```

So you need to change:

```
bimbam.py "C:\In\ExampleFile.exe" "C:\Out"
```

into

```
bimbam.py("C:\In\ExampleFile.exe" "C:\Out")
```

Hope that helps.